# How to solve a StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached error using Selenium Ubuntu EC2 using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract all data of column "Nb B" in this page : https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php

When I run my code from a Ubuntu PC It works perfectly but when I tried with EC2 Ubuntu It does not give me the good return.

Here is my server : ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20200611 (ami-0a63f96e85105c6d3)

Here is the python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php')

#Store url associated with the soccer games
url_links = []
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "match/cotes-")]'):
    url_links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

print(len(url_links), '\n')

nb_bookies = []
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@id and @role="row" ]/td[last()]'):
    nb_bookies.append(i.text)

print(nb_bookies)
```

Here is the output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./coteurchrome.py", line 25, in <module>
    url_links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 141, in get_attribute
    self, name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of the *href* attributes you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'match/cotes-')]")))])
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='match/cotes-']")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-millwall-blackburn-rid1109557.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-cardiff-derby-county-rid1109558.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-sheffield-w-huddersfield-rid1109559.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-luton-queens-park-rangers-rid1109563.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-chelsea-norwich-rid1109746.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-atalanta-brescia-rid1109694.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-gil-vicente-tondela-rid1109683.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-benfica-vitoria-guimaraes-rid1109899.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-orlando-city-new-york-city-fc-rid1109292.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-philadelphia-union-inter-miami-cf-rid1109809.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-ural-ekaterinburg-arsenal-tula-rid1109831.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-spartak-moscou-terek-akhmat-grozni-rid1109833.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-krylya-sovetov-fc-krasnodar-rid1109834.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-moreirense-pacos-ferreira-rid1109682.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-brentford-preston-rid1109561.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-bristol-c-stoke-rid1109568.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-fk-bodo-glimt-kristiansund-bk-rid1109735.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-molde-viking-rid1109736.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-sandefjord-aalesund-rid1109737.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-stromsgodset-mjondalen-rid1109738.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-valerenga-fk-haugesund-rid1109740.html', 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-shakhtar-donetsk-kolos-kovalivka-rid1109948.html']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but I can print the url with print(url_links)

Comment: In my case I want to extract the data of column "Nb B", last column of the table in the url page : https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php

Comment: @ahmedaao Observe the error stacktrace, your error is as `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./coteurchrome.py", line 25, in <module>
    url_links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))` which means the `href`s were not getting collected. Hence my answer.

Comment: I tried the same method for the column Nb B but I have again an error. Here is the line I tried :

Comment: print([my_elem for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@id and @role="row" ]/td[last()]")))])

Comment: @ahmedaao Can you raise a new question with the new requirement please? SO contributors will be happy to help you out.