# Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document while clicking on multiple links on the webpage using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, staleelementreferenceexception

I'm trying to click on every possible course links on this [page](https://catalog.maryville.edu/preview_program.php?catoid=18&poid=3085&_ga=2.22513656.232086776.1594848572-196623372.1594848572), but it gave me this error:

```
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

This is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://catalog.maryville.edu/preview_program.php?catoid=18&poid=3085&_ga=2.22513656.232086776.1594848572-196623372.1594848572')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="table_block_n2_and_content_wrapper"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/ul/li/span/a')

for link in links:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)
    time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

To click on all the course links on the page https://catalog.maryville.edu/preview_program.php?catoid=18&poid=3085&_ga=2.22513656.232086776.1594848572-196623372.1594848572 you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://catalog.maryville.edu/preview_program.php?catoid=18&poid=3085&_ga=2.22513656.232086776.1594848572-196623372.1594848572")
  links = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.acalog-course>span>a")))
  for link in links:
      link.click()
      time.sleep(3)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://catalog.maryville.edu/preview_program.php?catoid=18&poid=3085&_ga=2.22513656.232086776.1594848572-196623372.1594848572")
  links = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='acalog-course']/span/a")))
  for link in links:
      link.click()
      time.sleep(3)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion on [StaleElementReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62901619/how-to-solve-a-staleelementreferenceexception-message-stale-element-reference/62901813#62901813) in:

- [StaleElementException when iterating with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640973/staleelementexception-when-iterating-with-python/53646047#53646047)
- [Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073181/message-stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document-i/52075477#52075477)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your solution. I tried your code, but it skipped some links and there was an error: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" onclick="showCourse('18', '49507',this, 'a:2:{s:8:~location~;s:7:~program~;s:4:~core~;s:5:~10352~;}'); return false;">...</a> is not clickable at point (181, 528). Other element would receive the click: <div>...</div>

Comment: @Jasmine I guess this answer solves your initial issue of _stale element reference_